# preventing ajax call with tokeninput jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to use this plugin for multiple input fields. Sometimes I want to send a request to the backend to fetch the data, but sometimes, I just want the user to enter data (tags) and the entered data is placed into the field after a comma/or space. Can I configure this plugin to do something like this? Have anyone used the available functions to accomplish this? I'm thinking of just adding items using the functions they provide.